# How to sort Data class object in Array with LocalDate.now() in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I get this `ArrayList` named **items** containing several `Data class` in `Adapter`.

```
[DiaryCard(writeTime=2023-01-04, name=신혜정, stepCount=0, mood=2131230894, diary=안녕하세요), 
    DiaryCard(writeTime=2023-01-04, name=신혜정, stepCount=11, mood=2131230894, diary=hi), 
    DiaryCard(writeTime=2023-01-04, name=신태건, stepCount=0, mood=2131230898, diary=대단히 반갑습니다)]
```

I want to sort them by key 'writeTime' before I bind this data to View in `ViewHolder`.

```
   var items = items
    var sortItems = items.sortedBy { it.writeTime }

    inner class CardViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        var userWriteTime: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userWriteTime)
        var userNameView: TextView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.userName)
        var userStepCountView: TextView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.userStepCount)
        var userMoodView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.userMood)
        var userDiaryView: TextView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.userDiary)

        fun bind(position: Int) {
            Log.d("결과아", "items: $items")
            Log.d("결과아", "sortItems: $sortItems")

            userWriteTime.text = sortItems[position].writeTime
            userNameView.text = sortItems[position].name
            userStepCountView.text = "${sortItems[position].stepCount}보"
            userMoodView.setImageResource((sortItems[position].mood ?: 2131230873).toInt())
            userDiaryView.text = sortItems[position].diary

        }
    }
```

So I create `var sortItems` which sort items by using sortedBy.
And I link this sortItems var to function bind instead of items.
But it won't work.
When I print items and sortItems, the items shown above ArrayList contains 3 DiaryCard Data classes.
But sortItems show empty ListArray, [].

So How can I sort ArrayList by one component of DataClass?
Plus, my writeTime is String value coming from `LocalDate.now()`.
How can I sort them by `LocalDate.now()` in order for the most recent data to come first?
I use Kotlin, please help me with detailed code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`items.sortByDescending { item -> item.writeTime }`

The method sortByDescending mutates the original list sorting it descending using the size of the list as selector to make the comparison between elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sortByDescending` to get recents one first. [Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort-by-descending.html)

```
var sortItems = items.sortByDescending { it.writeTime }
```